# Finding set of solutions to $AX=0$ for triangular matrix $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $\ A = (a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$ be a triangular n × n-matrix, that is, $\ a_{i,j}=0$ if $1 ≤ j < i ≤ n$.
Assume none of diagonal elements is equal to zero.
Find the set of all solutions $X\in\Bbb{R}^n$ of equations $AX = 0$.

I think I figured out what the matrix looks like, is the solution just the transpose? If so, how does one prove that?

Comment: Since $A$ is triangular with no zero entries on the diagonal, $det(A)\neq 0$ so the only solution is $X=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $A$ is triangular, its determinant is the product of its diagonal entries. Because these are all non-zero, the determinant is non-zero. This means $A$ is invertible, and so $AX=0$ implies $X=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You know the last component of X has to equal zero (why?). So what does that imply?